# How to use select in findAllByAttributes in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have seen this:

```
    $makeModels = Make::model()->findAll(array("select"=>"fieldMake", "order"=>"fieldMake DESC"));
```

is it possible to do so with findAllByAttributes too? I need to only select one column values. I mean I don't want findAllByAttributes return array of object I need only an array of values.

Comment: don't use active record for custom select, or just override `afterFind()` method

Answer (score 0):

If you only want an array of values use a custom SQL command with `CDbCommand`

Take a look at the following url for more information:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand

It will probably look something like this:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('your sql query')->queryColumn();
```